# Upgrading spring-boot without upgrading mongodb driver in maven

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, upgrade

Context: in a project composed of 5 different applications and a 20 some packages, i try to update spring-boot (to 2.7.4) and only spring-boot, the project uses an internal enterprise artifactory, if that may have some impact. when i indicated that i need 2.7.4 some packages begun to use mongo-driver 4.6.2. Before it was 3.11.0. I went a head and updated it as well, by indicating in those pom.xml (where it was explicitly said 3.11.0 to use 4.6.2 instead). But that caused many unwanted errors (as some syntaxes have changed between those versions) So i went back to 3.11.0 and i explicitly indicated in all pom.xml that i want to use 3.11.0
The issue is that spring-boot now calls things in my mongodb-driver that are not there yet.

So the question is:  can i have spring-boot 2.7.4. with mongodb-driver 3.11.0 (and i am just missing how to tell it to use it correctly) **OR** that those versions are the strongly coupled with 4.6.2 so i have no choice but update that as well?
Also i did tried to find (for 2 days now), and i am sure it *should* exist for something so widely used as spring, but not found an explicit list that says "to upgrade from X->Y version of dependancy Z, here is the list of syntax changes that need to be made.", does it and how to find that?

Sorry for no concrete pom.xml exemples i am not on my work PC now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<exclusions>` tag for this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- dependency you want to exclude (with version) -->
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- The version you want as a dependency -->
        </dependency>
```